# How to create switcher with two string states?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to create a switch with two gender states - Man and Woman. I tried to create a Row of two buttons, but such a component will not support animation between the switch
[image]

As I said, I tried to create a Row of two buttons and also create a regular Switch component, but there was a problem with Switch as it doesn't allow accepting string constants into its body and it can't be resized

Comment: https://fvilarino.medium.com/creating-an-animated-selector-in-jetpack-compose-669066dfc01b custom layout??

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this. To add a shadow you can use Box behind Row items,

BlendMode is used to have fluid and partial text color change.
You can see in these answers how text color changes

[Jetpack Compose Canvas drawText color blending?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74723358/5457853)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75942019/5457853

[image]

```
fun ContentDrawScope.drawWithLayer(block: ContentDrawScope.() -> Unit) {
    with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
        val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)
        block()
        restoreToCount(checkPoint)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TextSwitch(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    selectedIndex: Int,
    items: List<String>,
    onSelectionChange: (Int) -> Unit
) {

    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .height(56.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .background(Color(0xfff3f3f2))
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        if (items.isNotEmpty()) {

            val maxWidth = this.maxWidth
            val tabWidth = maxWidth / items.size

            val indicatorOffset by animateDpAsState(
                targetValue = tabWidth * selectedIndex,
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 250, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing),
                label = "indicator offset"
            )

            // This is for shadow layer matching white background
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(x = indicatorOffset)
                    .shadow(4.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .width(tabWidth)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            )

            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()

                .drawWithContent {

                    // This is for setting black tex while drawing on white background
                    val padding = 8.dp.toPx()
                    drawRoundRect(
                        topLeft = Offset(x = indicatorOffset.toPx() + padding, padding),
                        size = Size(size.width / 2 - padding * 2, size.height - padding * 2),
                        color = Color.Black,
                        cornerRadius = CornerRadius(x = 8.dp.toPx(), y = 8.dp.toPx()),
                    )

                    drawWithLayer {
                        drawContent()

                        // This is white top rounded rectangle
                        drawRoundRect(
                            topLeft = Offset(x = indicatorOffset.toPx(), 0f),
                            size = Size(size.width / 2, size.height),
                            color = Color.White,
                            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(x = 8.dp.toPx(), y = 8.dp.toPx()),
                            blendMode = BlendMode.SrcOut
                        )
                    }

                }
            ) {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(tabWidth)
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .clickable(
                                interactionSource = remember {
                                    MutableInteractionSource()
                                },
                                indication = null,
                                onClick = {
                                    onSelectionChange(index)
                                }
                            ),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = text,
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            color = Color.Gray
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Demo

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun TextSwitchTest() {
    val items = remember {
        listOf("Man", "Woman")
    }

    var selectedIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }


    Column {
        TextSwitch(
            selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
            items = items,
            onSelectionChange = {
                selectedIndex = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: simple. just drawRoundedRect using offset. Much simpler than custom layout

Comment: @Raghunandan sure, if you have even width Tabs there is no need to change width of indicator, it's not required in this case you can do it like this. When you have Tabs with varying widths you can use `SubcomposeLayout` to pass tab widths and positions. https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:tv/tv-material/src/main/java/androidx/tv/material3/TabRow.kt;drc=7d44fa893370e5a1d5b95e1f7faa76a7f127a5a5;l=112